# How to get the last typed word in jtextpane?

Tags: java, string, input, jtextpane

How can I get the last typed word of a JTextPane? I am NOT asking for the last word of the string in the JTextPane. I want to store every typed word in a stack in the end, in order, and simply just getting the text on the JTextPane is not going to work.

For example, I type in "Hello World", then I add "My" in the middle, resulting to  "Hello My World". The last word typed is "My", not "World".

Most recent code using built in undo:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.undo.UndoManager;

import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class EditMenu{

    private JMenuItem undo;
    private JMenu editMenu;
    private TextEditor editor;
    private UndoManager manager;

    public test(TextEditor t){

        editor = t;     
        manager = new UndoManager(); 
        buildEditMenu();
    }
    public JMenu getEditMenu(){
        return editMenu;
    }
    private void buildEditMenu(){//create and add items to the edit menu

        editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        undo = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        setKeyListeners();
        editMenu.add(undo);
        editMenuListeners();
    }
    private void setKeyListeners() {//add listener for CTRL Z 

        editor.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z) && e.isControlDown()) {
                    undo();
                }
            }
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
        });     
    }
    private void editMenuListeners(){//create listeners for undo
        undoItemListener();
    }
    private void undoItemListener() {
        undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                undo();
            }
        });     
    }
    private void undo(){

        if(manager.canUndo())
            manager.undo();
        else
            System.out.println("cannot undo");
    }
}
```

.

```
class TextEditor extends JTextPane{

    public TextEditor(){
        super();
    }
    private JMenuBar buildMenus() {//create and add all the JMenus to the JMenuBar

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        EditMenu editMenu = new EditMenu(this);
        mb.add(editMenu.getEditMenu());

        return mb;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Editor");
        TextEditor editor = new TextEditor();

        frame.setContentPane(editor);
        frame.setJMenuBar(editor.buildMenus());//add the menu bar to the frame
        frame.setSize(1200, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);//exit on close
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well your requirements are not detailed enough. What if you type: "Helo World"? Does that give you two words? Then you realize your forgot the second "l" and go back to fix "Hello" Does that mean you know have 3 words "Helo", "World", "Hello"? What if you paste some text in the middle? Is that one word or do you need to parse the words in the text? What if you type "wor ld" and then remove the " "? Do you have 3 words "wor", "ld" "world". What is the real point of this?

Comment: Ahh good point, I completely forgot about that. Well in that case, I guess I would get the newest char added to the textpane, either if its typed or pasted. I'm creating my own undo feature for a text editor. Right now I am able to undo the last words of the string, but that is not the correct functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm creating my own undo feature for a text editor

That's what I thought you might be doing.

You should state that in your question. Tell us the requirement so we can understand what you are doing an maybe provide an alternative solution.

For example, you can check out the [Compound Undo Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/27/compound-undo-manager/). It attempts to merge character edits into a block edit, which is basically the way Word works.

Comment: I did take a look at that originally, but I could not figure it out for some reason. I created a UndoManager object and would attempt to make a call to undo(), but it would not work at all, since it canUndo() would be false everytime for some reason.

Comment: @bobdylan, its 3 lines of code. `and would attempt to make a call to undo(),` Where in the 3 lines does it do that? You just use the Actions to create either JMenuItems or JButtons. You don't need to add any manual code to invoke the undo/redo functions.

Comment: But I do use the actions of my menuItems. If the user clicks the menuItem, I check to see if the undoManger can undo or not. If it can, then I make a call to the built in undo(). But for some reason it can never undo() since canUndo() always returns false when something is typed and the undo button is clicked.

Comment: @bobdylan, `I check to see if the undoManger can undo or not` - what are you talking about? You don't need to do anything. The complete logic is contained in the Actions provided by the `CompoundUndoManager`. It is one line of code to create the menu item.  Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates how you are using the CompoundUndoManager. That is a JFrame with a JTextPane and a JMenuItem. The whole program would be about 20-30 lines of code.

Comment: I have posted my code. For some reason I could not import `CompoundUndoManager` so I used `UndoManager` instead.

Comment: @bobdylan, `I could not import CompoundUndoManager` did you download the code from the blog? The `CompoundUndoManager` is a custom class. You can't force the UndoManager to work like you want unless you customize its behaviour.

Comment: I did not even think about that. Thanks, I'm going to download it now and see if I can integrate it. In practice, is it okay to do something like this, like taking a large block of code, even if you provide the source?